# How to clean up or revert state changes done in unit test case?

Tags: c, unit-testing

Most (if not all) test frameworks have the concept of `Setup` and `Teardown` functions, where the `Setup` function is used to set up the necessary state for test cases and the `Teardown` function is used to clean up the state that was created in the `Setup` function.

What if my test case changes the state that was created by the `Setup` function? Where should I clean up or revert these changes? The `Teardown` function doesn't know what the test case might have changed, so it can't take care of that clean up. Does that mean that the clean up needs to happen in the test case itself?

Take, for example, some sort of 'Create' function that is under test. The test case for the 'Create' function will create an object and verify whether it was created correctly. After this verification, that object should be removed again so the next test case can start with a clean slate. Where should this be cleaned up?

The same goes for a 'Delete' function that is under test. As it wants to delete an object and verify the deletion was successful, it needs a `Setup` function that sets up this object. But how can the accompanying `Teardown` function know that the test case has already removed the object that the `Setup` function has created?

Comment: Run each unit test in different process. (See https://libcheck.github.io/check/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your test creates an object, your test should removed it.

Your TearDown method should removed the objects created only in your Setup method. The test must follow the Arrange-Act-Assert rule. After the Assert, recover the previous state.